# How can I combine a CTE with a Function, and use them in a recursive way?

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression, sql-function

I have a table `Element (id int, type nvarchar)`. Each element *may* have one or more parents, defined by *some* relation depending on it's type. Those parents may have their own set of parents defined by rule depending on it's *own* type.

What I want to do is to query for all `Element` records which are an ancestor (parent, parent's parent, ... ) of another element.

I've defined a function which, given an `id` and `type`, returns a list of parent's for that element.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetParentElementIds] (   
    @ElementId int,
    @ElementType nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS @ParentElementIds TABLE (id int primary key not null, type nvarchar(50) not null)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ElementType = 'channel' BEGIN
        DECLARE @PortId int

        -- Some logic to map the @ElementId to a related @PortId

        INSERT INTO @ParentElementIds VALUES (@PortId, 'port')
    END ELSE IF @ElementType = 'port' BEGIN
        DECLARE @CardId int

        -- Some logic to map the @ElementId to a related @CardId

        INSERT INTO @ParentElementIds VALUES (@CardId, 'card')
    END

    RETURN
END
```

... and that work's by itself. Next, I wanted to create a recursive CTE which repeatedly calls `GetParentElementIds()` on it's result set, to get a list of ancestors. Unfortunately, this is where my *master plan* begins to falter, and I'm not too sure on the correct query syntax:

```
WITH all_ancestor_elements (element_id, type)
AS (
    SELECT id AS element_id, type FROM Element WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.GetParentElementIds(5, 'channel'))
UNION ALL
    SELECT dbo.GetParentElementIds(e.id, e.type) FROM Element e WHERE e.id IN (SELECT element_id FROM all_ancestor_elements)
)

SELECT * FROM all_ancestor_elements;
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 465, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Recursive references are not allowed in subqueries

Any help would be apprechiated. I'm not forced into the current approach, and would gladly welcome any better ones; this is simply the path I chose as seeming the best at the time!

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are calling your table valued function here:

```
SELECT dbo.GetParentElementIds(e.id, e.type) FROM Element e
```

You would need to use something like:

```
SELECT  g.id, g.type
FROM    Element e 
        CROSS APPLY dbo.GetParentElementIds(e.id, e.type) g
```

I am not 100% sure of your exact logic but I'd guess your final query would end up something like:

```
WITH all_ancestor_elements (element_id, type)
AS (
    SELECT  id AS element_id, type 
    FROM    Element 
    WHERE   id IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.GetParentElementIds(5, 'channel'))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  g.id, g.type
    FROM    all_ancestor_elements e 
            CROSS APPLY dbo.GetDirectAffectorElementIds(e.element_id, e.type) g
)
SELECT  * 
FROM    all_ancestor_elements;
```

Comment: Humm... unfortunately I've got over 1 million rows in the `Element` table. If I construct the individual parts of the query manually, the CTE anchor runs in under 1ms, returning a single row. Running that result on the recursive case returns another single result, and running that on the recursive case returns no results... therefore we should be done. Each of those 3 queries takes < 1ms, yet when running the CTE as a, urr, CTE it runs for over 5 minutes... any ideas how to optimize the query you've formed?

Comment: It's really hard to say with no sample data to work with, can you post some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and I will see what I can do?

Comment: I really apprechiate the willingness to take a look, but unfortunately the "some logic" I've omitted from my function is quite complex, and uses multiple other tables in my database; it won't be easy to put onto SQLFiddle! However, I've changed your recursive case to `SELECT  g.id, g.type
  FROM    all_ancestor_elements e 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetDirectAffectorElementIds(e.element_id, e.type) g` and it now seems to work as expected, and takes < 1 ms to execute.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I was guessing somewhat at what to put in the recursive member.